# Change background color based on drop down value in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

i have an excel spread sheet which has a cell called status of reminder, this cell is a drop down cell which has values such as "Reminder 1 sent" it could be any number of Reminder, and there are cells called reminder 1, 2 , 3...n number of reminders , i also have a cell called suspension date, all the reminder cells are coded to automatically changes to two weeks after the suspension date is sent which works fine, the idea is that i want to change the background color of the reminder cells based on the value in the drop down list. say drop down has Reminder 1 sent , reminder 1 cell should be green , reminder 2 sent , reminder 2 should be green.

**heres my apps script code:**

```
function fillReminders() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;

  var spreadSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sample");

  var suspensionDate = sheet.getRange(4, 4).getValue();
  var dropDownValue = sheet.getRange(4, 3).getValue();

  var email = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  
  var analystName = sheet.getRange(4,1).getValue();

  var caseId = sheet.getRange(4,2).getValue();

 // MailApp.sendEmail(email, analystName +" -" + caseId + " - Case Clinic Reminder", "Hi this is not working :D");


  if (suspensionDate) {
    var baseColumn = 5;
    var numberOfReminders = 6;

      for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfReminders; i++) {
        var reminder = new Date(suspensionDate);
        reminder.setDate(reminder.getDate() + (i - 1) * 14);
        var reminderCell = sheet.getRange(4, baseColumn + i - 1);

        var currentDate = new Date();

        if (reminder < currentDate) {
        var reminderStatus = "Reminder " + i + " sent";

        if (dropDownValue === reminderStatus) {
          reminderCell.setBackground("green");
          
        } else {
          reminderCell.setBackground("red");
        }
      } else {

        reminderCell.setBackground(null);
      }

        reminderCell.setValue(reminder);
        currentColumn++;
      }
    }
   else {
    sheet.getRange(4, 5, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 4).clearContent();
  }
}
```

for some reason it only changes reminder 1 cell's background color to no matter what the value inside the drop down is, is there a way to  fix this and dynamically update each reminder cell based on the drop down value?

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can replicate and better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1");
    const clrs = ["red", "green", "orange", "blue", "violet","yellow"];
    let r = e.range.getDataValidation();
    if(r) {
      //e.source.toast("Gate2");
      let arr = r.getCriteriaValues()[0].map(e => parseInt(e));
      let idx = arr.indexOf(parseInt(e.value));  
      if(~idx) e.range.setBackground(clrs[idx % 6]);
    }
  }
}
```

My Sheet0:

[image]

Depending upon the actual content of your criteriaValues this might be a better solution for you.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    e.source.toast("Gate1");
    const clrs = ["red", "green", "orange", "blue", "violet", "yellow"];
    let r = e.range.getDataValidation();
    if (r) {
      e.source.toast("Gate2");
      Logger.log(r.getCriteriaValues());
      let arr = r.getCriteriaValues()[0];
      let idx = arr.indexOf(e.value);
      Logger.log('idx: %s arr: %s',idx,JSON.stringify(arr));
      if (~idx) e.range.setBackground(clrs[idx % 6]);
    }
  }
}
```

It's hard to say without knowing exactly what your particular criteriaValues are.